Sticky Footer Below Content in Ionic Web App
I'm building an Ionic app that I also plan to deploy as a web app. For the web version, I want to add a footer that sticks below the content on every page, so the footer only appears when the user scrolls to the bottom of the content.
To make this work, I removed <ion-content> and <ion-footer>, as they didn't allow the layout I’m aiming for. I also had to use #scrollingOuterDiv and #scrollingDiv to manage the scrolling behavior, but I’m not satisfied with this approach and would prefer a cleaner solution if possible.
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </ion-header>

  <div #scrollingOuterDiv class="flex flex-col h-screen overflow-auto">
    <div #scrollingDiv class="overflow-auto flex-grow min-h-[88vh] scroll-hide relative">
      @if(globalStateService.isLoading()) {
        <ion-spinner class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 z-50" name="circular"></ion-spinner>
      }
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer class="flex-shrink-0"></app-footer>
  </div>
</ion-app>

Dependencies:
Here are the dependencies I'm currently using:
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
  "@capacitor/android": "6.1.2",
  "@capacitor/app": "6.0.1",
  "@capacitor/core": "6.1.2",
  "@capacitor/geolocation": "^6.0.1",
  "@capacitor/google-maps": "^6.0.1",
  "@capacitor/haptics": "6.0.1",
  "@capacitor/ios": "6.1.2",
  "@capacitor/keyboard": "6.0.2",
  "@capacitor/preferences": "^6.0.2",
  "@capacitor/status-bar": "6.0.1",
  "@ionic/angular": "^8.0.0",
  "ionicons": "^7.2.1",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
}


To replicate this issue, follow these simple steps:

Create a new blank Ionic Angular application.
Replace the content of app.component.html with the following code:

<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  <div>
    Footer
  </div>
</ion-app>


Run the app, and you’ll notice that the footer is not visible as expected. Note: The goal is to have the footer positioned below the content, not as a sticky footer.


please share working example on stackblitz, steps to replicate and expected output

To replicate this issue, follow these simple steps:

Create a new blank Ionic Angular application.
Replace the content of app.component.html with the following code:

<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  <div>
    Footer
  </div>
</ion-app>


Run the app, and you’ll notice that the footer is not visible as expected. Note: The goal is to have the footer positioned below the content, not as a sticky footer.

